# ViewModelBuilder returning variable null. Not retrieving state

Tags: flutter, dart, state, state-management

I am refactor app to use stacked but have issue. State not seem to be pass correct between widget.

I added ViewModelBuilder at top of the widget tree that I want to affect.

```
  return ViewModelBuilder<vehicleData>.reactive(
                    builder: (context, model, child){
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                        child: InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                          child: Card(
                            //color: Colors.blueGrey,
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: AspectRatio(
                                  aspectRatio: 0.8,
                                  child: Image.network(
                                    //data.images,
                                    snapshot.data.documents[index]['icon'],
                                    height: 500,
                                    //width: 300,
                                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                  )
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                //data.make,
                                snapshot.data.documents[index]['make'],
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                              ),
                              onTap: (){
                                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                                //ProformaScreen(data.make),
                                ProformaScreen(snapshot.data.documents[index]['make']),
                                  ),
                                );
                                model.setModel(snapshot.data.documents[index]['model']);
                              } ,
                            ),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                      viewModelBuilder: ()=> vehicleData(),
                    );
```

This calls model.setModel and assign the model based on the selected car.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';

class vehicleData extends BaseViewModel{
  String _make;
  String _images;
  var _model;

   setModel(var model){
    _model = model;
    print ('This is the Model of the Car \n');
    print (_model);
    notifyListeners();
  }

   setMake(String make){
    _make = make;
    notifyListeners();
  }
   setImages(String images){
    _images = images;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  get getModel => print('This is within the Get ' + _model);
  get getMake => _make;
  get getImage => _images;
}
```

Both print statement return correct model I still can see them.
But when I try call using ViewModelBuilder in another page model return null:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gerente_loja/core/services/vehicle_data.dart';
import 'package:stacked/stacked.dart';

class menuModel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _menuModelState createState() => _menuModelState();
}
class _menuModelState extends State<menuModel> {

  var carModel;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   String selectModel;

    return ViewModelBuilder<vehicleData>.reactive(
        builder: (context, modelView, child){
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 16.0),
          child: DropdownButton(
            hint: Text('Ano'),
            dropdownColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 5,
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            isExpanded: true,
            iconSize: 36.0,
            value: selectModel,
            onChanged: (value){
              setState(() {
                print (modelView.getModel);

                selectModel = value;
              });
            },
            items: carModel.map((value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem (
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value));
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      );
     },
      viewModelBuilder: ()=> vehicleData(),
    );
  }

}
```

print (modelView.getModel); is null.
Anyone know why model return null? I have look hard to solve but no idea why.

Comment: You shouldn't use same ViewModel for two different Views. You should create two different ViewModel and pass the data of "car model" to your menu view (menuModel)

Comment: @MdAzharuddin thx for the feedback, Just a quick question is that the purpose of using state management to keep your data alive as long as the app is up and running or until you dispose of it. Because for what am getting from you is like for each view I should ahve a different BaseViewModel. Because my ViewModelBuilder of the type vehicleData that holds the information I need to display in menu model. Can you please give me an example based on my use case if possible. Thanks